# Why this code is giving output as none. I was trying to get the reversed output

Tags: string, list, split, reverse, nonetype

Why the following code is giving me output as none. Basically, I attempt to get the output as Lastname Firstname.
So I used split() so that it will return me the list and then I tried to reverse the list using `reverse()`.
Though I'm getting output as none.

CODE:

```py
fn="FirstName LastName".split(" ")
a=fn.reverse()
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.reverse()` changes list "in-place", so your `a` variable is `None`.

Try:

```
fn = "FirstName LastName".split(" ")
fn.reverse()
print(" ".join(fn))
```

Prints:

```
LastName FirstName
```